# Json file does not working for the C program in visual studio code

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am using **Visual studio code** on windows. I already installed 64-bit Minigw on my computer.

I have done this following simple program as testing purpose on vs code

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
        int a,b,c;
        printf("enter the no.");
        scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
        c=a+b;
        printf("%d",c);
        return 0;
    }
```

and the corresponding json file is:

```
{
    "configurations": [{
        "name": "Win64",
        "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
        "includePath": [
            "C:/MinGW/include/c++/3.4.5",
            "${workspaceRoot}"

        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE"
        ],
        "compileCommands": "",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "C:/MinGW/include/c++/3.4.5",
                "${workspaceRoot}"

            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    }],
    "version": 3
}
```

Now when I take the cursor to the #include  it stil shows the following error:

`#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. IntelliSense features 
 for this translation unit (C:\Users\h\Documents\vsc\prg1.cpp) will be provided 
 by the Tag Parser.
 cannot open source file "stdio.h"`

And in the problem section of **Visual Studio code** those 8 problems are showing:-

[image]

[image]

I have no idea what to do? plz help-Thank you

Comment: If my answer below solved your problem, you should mark it as the accepted answer. It is rude to expect people to spend their time for you and then to disregard the effort they made to help. If it did not help, you should comment on the answer explaining what went wrong.

Comment: @coding_ninza, What about this issue? Whether qreon's suggestion is helpful for you? If it is helpful, you could mark it as the answer, if not, feel free to share the latest information in your side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume the JSON file you provided is your Visual Studio project configuration.

In that file, the `"includePath"` field is the field telling Visual Studio where to look for headers. This field is set to two locations:

- your working directory,
- `C:/MinGW/include/c++/3.4.5`, which contains standard C++ headers.

`<stdio.h>` is a standard C header, so Visual Studio cannot find it within the C++ headers. For a quick fix, you can try to include `<cstdio>` instead.

If you want to do things the clean way, you'll need to change the project configuration to find standard C headers:

- Right click your project in the solution explorer
- Go to `Properties`
- Under the `C++ > General` section, find the `Additional include directories` field
- Append to its value the path to the directory containing the C headers. It should be something like `C:/MinGW/include/`, but you may need to check it by yourself, as it depends on your MinGW installation.

**Edit:** just noticed you were talking about VSCode and not Visual Studio. In that case simply add `"C:/MinGW/include/"` to the `includePath` array in the JSON file and disregard the following.

This method will only affect the current project, so you may need to do it again for other projects. If you want to make it permanent so that future solutions are affected too, open the `Tools` menu and go to `Options`. On the sidebar, find `Projects and solutions` and go to `VC++ directories`. Then you can append the directory path to the include path field in here. **However, this functionnality was disabled in VS2013 and later versions.**

*Additional note:* Visual Studio can do C, but it is not what it was tailored for. Although a C compiler will be used for any file with a `.c` extension, there exist **no solution or project type** in Visual Studio that was designed for C programs.

Comment: I don't know if this answer is good but deserve an upvote anyway ;)